# `$(function` not getting invoked after submit button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, stripe-payments

I am using stripe.js to learn custom payment, I am using .net MVC to create a simple website that handles payment. I am fairly new to webdev and cannot for life of me figure out why this js function is not being invoked after submit button click, I am putting the token into ViewBag for now just so I have a way to view the data. Further context, I want to process the token server side while generating the token client side. I am probably missing something simple, but at this point I have tried everything I could find.

Here is the code I am using to test the card charge.
This is a partial cshtml file, that upon data entry this cshtml will be displayed by calling `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/processors.cshtml")`

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System
@using System.Web.UI
@model Dependency_Injection_MEF_MVC.Models.Payment

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_rob8TRTyyRseiTwrqSmheKiZ');
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var $form = $('#payment-form');
            $form.submit(function (event) {
                // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
                $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

                // Request a token from Stripe:
                Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

                // Prevent the form from being submitted:
                return false;
            });
        });

        function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
            // Grab the form:
            var $form = $('#payment-form');

            if (response.error) { // Problem!

                // Show the errors on the form:
                $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
                $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

            } else { // Token was created!

                // Get the token ID:
                var token = response.id;

                // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
                $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="Token">').val(token));

                // Submit the form:
                $form.get(0).submit();
            }
        };
    </script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-column">
        <div class="form-container">
            <form asp-controller="home" asp-action="InvoicePayment" method="POST" id="payment-form">
                <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3>Membership Amount: USD XX</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cardNumber">Card Number</label>
                    <input class="form-control form-input" id="cardNumber" type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" style= "width:250px;height:25px;font-size:120%">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Expiration (MM/YY)</label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="form-control form-input date-input" type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month" style= "width:250px;height:25px;font-size:120%">
                        <input class="form-control form-input date-input" type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year" style= "width:250px;height:25px;font-size:120%">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cvc">CVC</label>
                    <input class="form-control form-input" id="cvc" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" style= "width:250px;height:25px;font-size:120%">
                </div>

                <input class="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Payment">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors showing in the browser developer console when you click Submit?

Comment: nope it just POSTS and then resets the page

Comment: I have another button outside this partial view that also posts based on `id=submit` would that be a confliction you think? it should't right since this is only concerning `id="payment-form"` since `var $form = $('#payment-form');`

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in the browser debugger does it step through all of the code? I've seen issues where it will submit without running the code. You could always try a `.click()` and just do `$("#formId").submit()` or something

Comment: I think that is what is happening, I am still new to using the debugger in windows. The debugger in Visual Studio does not even hit that point since JS debugging in cshtml is probably not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript runs before the actual form you're targeting exists. You need to move it to after the form HTML, or even better, just before the closing body tag.

**UPDATE**

The only things that can cause your event handler to not get fired would be:

1. It doesn't bind to form. This could be caused by a number of factors, one of which being the original issue discussed above. So, like I said, your JavaScript must run after the HTML it targets, so don't move it back simply because it's still not working. There's additional issues at play. It could also be caused by the selector not matching, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.
2. There's an JavaScript error that's preventing the script from running. JavaScript breaks on error, so any further JavaScript will not run. However, you've claimed that there's no errors being reported, so this doesn't seem to be the issue either.
3. The only other thing is that JavaScript included as part of an HTML response to an AJAX request *is not run*. Although, you haven't explicitly mentioned AJAX, your question seems to indicate that this form might be being displayed as the result of an AJAX request. For security, browsers will escape any script tags in an AJAX response, so you're just flat out of luck there. Your only option is to include this script as part of the main view and then defer your event handler binding. For example:

   ```
   $(body).on('submit', '#payment-form', function () {
   ```

   This will allow you bind to `#payment-form` even though it doesn't currently exist on the page, as you're actually binding to `body` and jQuery will simply forward to the handling of `#payment-form` once the event bubbles up to there. However, you should not actually bind to `body`. I did that just because that's guaranteed to work, but it's also highly inefficient. You should pick the absolute closest parent to your payment form that exists at the time of binding (i.e. not something that's included in the AJAX response).

Comment: Ok trying this right now, but I was certain I had tried that before. I will let you know shortly.Thanks!

Comment: There may indeed potentially be other issues at play that will need to further be resolved, but you're definitely going nowhere with the JavaScript running before the form exists, so that's step 1.

Comment: Nope still get nothing except it posts and then resets the whole page. The HTML loads fine, but the js method is not getting invoked for some reason!! you are correct, its really hard to debug and find out why it is happening, do you know of a way to debug and find where the root of them problem is??

Comment: Thanks alot for the update, I think its clear to me now. I initially had `@section scripts` that didnt work as to @secion scripts as far as I have read wont work in partial views. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes, you cannot use `@section` in a partial. Partials are rendered in a subprocess of the main view rendering, and as a result, do not have access to the layout to apply such changes.